# How to package node.js application in jenkins?

Tags: node.js, jenkins

After build happens in Jenkins,Iam trying to do package of node.js application in jenkins

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find the [NodeJS Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin) provides the functionality you are describing.